# understanding what affects script speed

Tags: performance, webserver

Hi (not sure if in the right forum)

I'm currently using hostpapa for my webhost. During development on my apache server all my scripts (javascript, php etc) all run well and reasonable speed. However when I placed on the live server i noticed a considerable delay in php and javascript.

I've timed a colorbox call which took 5600ms to complete loading (on host papa)- an age when staring at the screen.

So I decided to look for another host. Currently I'm trialling 34esp and 1and1. 34esp takes between 2400 and 5000ms to load (sometimes considerably longer). 1and1 takes between 1300 and 1700ms.

hostpapa is a us based server, 34sp and 1and1 are uk based (im uk based).
So - what affects speed so much? Is this network related or down to the servers being used? What other tests can I carry out to help me determine the best server to choose?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems is about PHP script, the question is ambiguous. In general speaking depending of a lot of factors. From example is involved type of the server, or PHP engine. Also, you can have implementation of PHP in C or Java [Quercus](http://quercus.caucho.com/) for Glassfish. Take a look on [Benchmark and Optimize PHP Script Speed](http://www.webdesign.org/web-programming/php/benchmark-and-optimize-php-script-speed.14875.html).